# How to properly unescape non-ASCII cahracters in location.pathname

Tags: javascript, url

I have the following URL in the browser address bar:

> example.com/search/city/Germany:Baden-Württemberg

From the console I try to get the pathname of the URL:

`location.pathname` which returns:

> /search/city/Germany:Baden-W%C3%BCrttemberg

I see that the **ü** character has been transformed (escaped) to **%C3%BC** sequence.
I want to dysplay this character as is in the HTML document, therefore I tryed with unescapeing it:

`unescape(location.pathname)` but unfortunatelly what I get is not the string from the URL >
'/search/city/Germany:Baden-WÃ¼rttemberg'

How can I get the URL character **ü** (from my URL `example.com/search/city/Germany:Baden-Württemberg` ) via Javascript ?

Thank you!

Comment: Use [`decodeURI()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/decodeURI)

Comment: By the way, from the documentations of [`unescape()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape) : *"Note: Do not use unescape to decode URIs, use decodeURI instead."*. Sometime (always) reading the documentation helps

Comment: If I knew the answer is there I would have read it. window is pretty big API. You know learning by doing is often effective way.
In general you are right, but the due dates not aways encopas API documentation reading time.

Comment: I voted to close this question because you indicate that you resolved the problem without receiving any answers. If you still need answers, please [edit] the question to indicate that the issue is not fully resolved. If the solution you found would be useful to others, please answer your own question by pressing the "Answer Your Question" button.

Comment: @Hairi well, reading the documentation of the function you used to know why it didn't work as expected would have been a great pointer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution pointed out by @Cid

> Use decodeURI()

worked better in this case than `unescape` which seems not to be the preferred function for such translations.

From  [developer.mozilla.org](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/unescape)

> Usually, decodeURI or decodeURIComponent are preferred over unescape.

Again, all the credits of this answer go to @Cid for his comments on the original questions.